# Akka actors mysteriously dying in middle of job

Tags: java, akka

So I'm doing image processing with Akka actors via Java and have a function that applies a transformation one pixel at a time.  It does so in the standard way - nested for loops for rows and columns.  The information for the image is loaded into 2D array and each actor is given a start row and an end row.

The issue I'm running into is that, when I spin up any more than one single actor, all actors except the first die relatively quickly into execution.

For example - I've got code similar to this running on the actors:

```
for (int row = this.startRow; row <= this.endRow; row++) {
        System.out.println("Running for row " + row);
}
```

Lots of other stuff obviously happens within that for loop, but the concerning part is here:

If I spin up one actor and say that its startRow is 0 and its endRow is 1000, the process runs exactly as expected.  In my terminal window, I get a list of numbers from 0 to 1000.  Makes total sense!

The issue arrives when I add another actor.  If I create two actors:

1. startRow 0, endRow 500
2. startRow 501, endRow 1000

My console output looks like this:

```
Running for row 0
Running for row 501
Running for row 1
Running for row 502
Running for row 2
Running for row 503
Running for row 3
Running for row 504
Running for row 4
Running for row 505
Running for row 5
Running for row 506
Running for row 6
Running for row 7
Running for row 8
Running for row 9
Running for row 10
Running for row 11
Running for row 12
Running for row 13
Running for row 14
Running for row 15
Running for row 16
Running for row 17
Running for row 18
Running for row 19
Running for row 20
```

And it generally goes exactly 6 rows before it stops executing.  I feel it's also important to mention that no errors are thrown whatsoever.  I don't have the code implemented to export the image yet, but even if I did, that wouldn't stop my second actor from dying after 6-7 iterations.

Comment: How many threads in your dispatcher? You made any changes for `parallelism-factor`? From what you posted, cannot see any special, you may need to post a workable code so someone may can help you.

Comment: It was an issue unrelated to Akka.  My second actor would go out of bounds on the array, but due to how I had my try/catch block nesting set up the error was getting caught but ignored.